# d3 Pie Chart - Image on Outside Label

Tags: d3.js, pie-chart

Hi am trying to place an image on an outside label of a pie chart. Setting an img or image tag will show the tag written on the label.

replacing all text values does not work like:

```
var svgs =  d3.selectAll("text");            
    svgs.append("svg:image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "/web/images/edit.png")
      .attr("width", 24)
      .attr("height", 24);
```

Cannot believe that a simple thing like this cannot be  made simple.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't specific enough for a concrete answer but as an example, I've taken this [nice pie chart](http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799) and modified to replace one of the labels with an image:

```
var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
    .data(pie(data), key);

var img = svg.select(".images").selectAll("image")
  .data(pie(data), key);

 text.enter()
    .append("text")
    .filter(function(d,i){
      return d.data.label !== "do";  //<-- on the "do" label suppress the text
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.label;
    });

text.transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
        this._current = this._current || d;
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
        this._current = interpolate(0);
        return function(t) {
            var d2 = interpolate(t);
            var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
            pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
            return "translate("+ pos +")";
        };
    })
    .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d){
        this._current = this._current || d;
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
        this._current = interpolate(0);
        return function(t) {
            var d2 = interpolate(t);
            return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start":"end";
        };
    });

function midAngle(d){
    return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2;
}

text.exit()
    .remove();

img.enter()
    .append("image")
    .filter(function(d,i){
      return d.data.label === "do"; //<-- only add image on "do"
    })
    .attr("xlink:href", "http://placehold.it/24x24")
.attr("width", 24)
.attr("height", 24);

img.transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
        this._current = this._current || d;
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
        this._current = interpolate(0);
        return function(t) {
            var d2 = interpolate(t);
            var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
            pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
            return "translate("+ pos +")";
        };
    })

img.exit()
    .remove();
```

Here's a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/8lTfBrAmyxPF7A5S6L33?p=preview).

[image]

**EDITS FOR COMMENTS**

My original answer was straight d3, but since you are using another library, [d3pie](http://d3pie.org/), do it like this after calling d3pie:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var labelG = d3.select('#p0_labelGroup1-outer');
    labelG.select('text').remove();
    labelG
      .append("svg:image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "http://lorempixel.com/60/60/animals/")
      .attr("width", 61)
      .attr("height", 61)
      .attr("x", -20)
      .attr("y", -30);
    }, 10);
```

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dVhAn3txNih50oGoMN4I?p=preview).

Comment: Great yes, i am looking for an image like this but on a regular basic d3 pie not a donut. My javascript is too bad i cannot transfer this info to the the regular pie. There are no .labels classes. Dont understand why selectAll("text") aint working like above.

Comment: @user1786641, your code above won't work because it'll append an image as a child of a `text` element.  This isn't valid SVG.  Create an example Plunker or JSFiddle so I can see what you are doing.

Comment: In my regular Pie SVG the labels are stored in such tags:<text id="p25_segmentMainLabel1-outer" class="p25_segmentMainLabel-outer" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: arial; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51);">TEXT OF LABEL</text> So I thought d3.selectAll("text") returns all svg Label elements i need to modify

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/waVnqP2RqJTCqoIR9gUw?p=preview
unfortunately d3pie sources are not available so u wont see

Comment: @user1786641, see new answer above.  For future questions please include all relevant details and examples.  For instance, if I had known you were using `d3pie` and not straight `d3` it would have save me a bit of time.